# How to detect if a textfield is empty in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfielddelegate

Hello despite the question name, this question requests a bit more insight.

I want to know how to check if a textfield is empty but it must be able to detect this if contained text previously.

Here is my current code

```
 func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    if textField == txtSitReach {

        if txtSitReach.text != nil {

            doneSitReachButton.enabled = true
        }
        else {
            doneSitReachButton.enabled = false
        }
    }
    else {
        print("whatever")
    }
```

Comment: if txtSitReach.text.isEmpty == true

Comment: no that solution invoked some very odd behavior. Essentially that did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixing the other answer:

```
txtSitReach.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textDidChange), forControlEvents: .EditingChanged)

func textDidChange(textField: UITextField) {
    doneSitReachButton.enabled = !txtSitReach.text!.isEmpty
}
```

Comment: Nothing big, but you could have just edited my question and added the `!`. Now there are two "exact" the same answers, which could confuse other people. Just a tip for next time ;).

Answer (score 4):

You could add a target checking the textfield when some changes has been made (i.e. adding some characters).

```
txtSitReach.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textDidChange), forControlEvents: .EditingChanged)

func textDidChange(textField: UITextField) {
    doneSitReachButton.enabled = txtSitReach.text?.isEmpty ?? false
}
```

Comment: This is so close! It does the opposite of what I want though. When the textfield is empty it is enabled  and when it has text it is disabled

Comment: You can add a `!` in front of `txtSitReach.text?.isEmpty` to do the opposite though. It wasn't very clear what you exactly wanted in your question :).